# SSRS order number with (-)

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS i am trying to sort a group of number as an example down.
The numbers are like

```
3-102
3-202
10-102
10-502
12-802
```

When I just sorted without expression it pulls first number 10.
Then I tried to used **val(fields!apt.value)** expression.

Then it sorted only first numbers 3, 10 ad 12. Second numbers wasn't in order

How to sort these numbers as I order at the top. Which function should I use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add 2 sort expressions (or combine them into 1 but 2 is easier IMO)

The first expression will be

```
=VAL(SPLIT(Fields!apt.Value, "-")(0))
```

and the second

```
=VAL(SPLIT(Fields!apt.Value, "-")(1))
```

All we are doing here is splitting the `apt` string using `-` as the delimiter, into an array, then taking the first element (0) for the first expression. The second expression is exactly the same but we take the second element (1).

Then we use `VAL()` (as you tried)

Below is the output. The left table is unsorted. The right table uses the sort expression above

[image]

---

### Edit after OP update

If you have instances where `apt` field does not contain a `"-"` then you will need to change the **SECOND expression only**

```
=IIF(SPLIT(Fields!apt.Value, "-").Length > 1
, SPLIT(Fields!apt.Value & "-", "-")(1)
, "")
```

This simply adds adds some text to fake the missing part so the `SPILT()` function always returns at least 2 elements.

Comment: Yes, copy/paste and forgot the edit - thanks. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is giving error. when i write it "(0))" parts underline red.

Comment: Ignore that, the intellisense is not very good. It will work. Also, make sure your field name (`apt`) is spelled correctly, it is case sensitive,

Comment: That is work, Thank you. But i have another question. i couldnt think that couse problem. i have 'apt' values like without string. And these are in other groups. Like this one in A site, sorting. and i have B site sorting in themself. Other apt values are like 1232, 3234, 4356, etc. when i do that, other sites gave an error, this site worked perfect.

Comment: I've updated the answer. If this resolves your problem, please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark under the vote up/down buttons)